# What is the fastest way to count the number of lines in a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, performance

I'm looking for the most performant way to count the number of lines in a string in JavaScript for a string of any length. I have tested three approaches, but I feel like there may be a faster way that one of you is aware of.

Method 1:

```
// Split the string on newlines into an array and measure the array length
return string.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/g).length;
```

Method 2:

```
// Use match instead of split
return (string.match(/\r|\r\n|\n/g) || '').length + 1;
```

Method 3:

```
// Replace all of the newlines with empty space and compare line lengths
return string.length - string.replace(/\r|\r\n|\n/g, '').length + 1;
```

Comment: Any technique will involve a linear traversal of the string.

Comment: Can't you just count the `\n` or `\r` characters and add one? Why would you split strings or replace anything? Why would you use a regular expression? A file either contains `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n` as line break. It won't change inside the same file. Your approaches look very inefficient.

Comment: maybe `[...string].reduce((count,chr,i,{[i+1]:nxt})=>count+(nxt!=='\n'&&(chr==='\r'||chr==='\n')?1:0 ,1)`  is faster ?

Comment: @MisterJojo Depending on the number of line breaks it could be faster to find the first occurrence of `\r` or `\n` and to count only this one character. A common loop and string index access should be faster than `[...string].reduce`

Comment: All three methods don't even work for texts using `\r\n` as line break: https://jsfiddle.net/b8jwmdq0/ In this snippet, I've tested all three methods with texts containing 5 lines. All three methods count 9 lines for the text containing `\r\n`. You shouldn't ask a for a faster method. You should ask for a working method. Your methods count `\r\n` as two different line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Find the first occurrence of a possible line break character and count this character:

```js
function countLines(string) {
  let count = 1;

  let chr;
  let i = 0, end = string.length;
  for (; i < end; ++i) {
    if (string[i] == '\n' || string[i] == '\r') {
      count = 2;
      chr = string[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  for (++i; i < end; ++i) {
    if (string[i] == chr) {
      ++count;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

const linuxString = 'Some\ntext\nwith\nfive\nlines';
const windowsString = 'Some\r\ntext\r\nwith\r\nfive\r\nlines';
const classicMacString = 'Some\rtext\rwith\rfive\rlines';

console.log(countLines(linuxString));
console.log(countLines(windowsString));
console.log(countLines(classicMacString));
```

Comment: Is this faster than .match?

Comment: @KirkOuimet According to [JSBench](https://jsbench.me/), the line `(string.match(/\r|\r\n|\n/g) || '').length + 1;` is 8.17% slower than my code, even for the short text in my example. I assume, the gap becomes larger for longer texts.